# How to create a mySQL table with specified field length?

Tags: mysql, string-length

It should be fairly easy but I don't seem to find the answer anywhere else.

If for example I have the following table how do I set the `LastName` field to be of an exact size? (not maximum)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255)
)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: CHAR?. [11.4.1 The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html).

Comment: Are you trying to enforce a minimum length or make the field a fixed length as these are very different.

Comment: so use padding to fill in the missing characters? I wanted it to fail or something. Like trying to insert a value at a non existent field.

Comment: You can try to use triggers to make sure the size fits. In the trigger, if the size is not what you want, you raise an error. But it would be best to achieve this in your server-side language imho.

Comment: sounds good to me. Thanks for the replies. And btw what is wrong with the question and got voted down?

Comment: what I want to do is to have either an value of `LastName` that is lets say 10 characters long or not have it at all. Reject the input as it is not an existing field! And from what I have read if I have `LastName varchar(255)` then the input `abc` would still be correct. Which means the above doesn't have to be 255 characters every time

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you cannot set a minimum/exact length for a VARCHAR field in MySQL.

You can handle that using PHP, something like:

```
if(strlen($field) == $requiredLength)
     //add to database
else   
    echo "incorrect length";
```

If you are not using PHP, you can implement something similar with your server-side language.

Comment: That is what the maximum length of the varchar can be. Doesn't specify the exact number which is acceptable.

Comment: I am not using PHP but as @Marko said I can implement something similar on my server-side implementation. Thanks